# Image of homomorphism with kernel $N$ isomophic to $M/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $N$ be a submodule. Let $f:M\rightarrow M'$ be a surjective homomorphism with kernel $N$. How to show that $M'$ is isomorphic to $M/N$?

My thought: Define $g:M/N\rightarrow M'$ by $g(a+N)=f(a)$.

Then
$$g((a+N)+(b+N))=g(a+b+N)=f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)=g(a+N)+g(b+N)$$
$$g((a+N)r)=g(ar+N)=f(ar)=f(a)r=g(a+N)r$$

So $g$ is a homomorphism.

For any $a\notin N$, $g(a+N)=f(a)\ne0$. Therefore the kernel of $g$ is $N$ only.

Hence we conclude that $g$ is an isomorphism and hence $M'\approx M/N$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Look at the first isomorphism Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem

Comment: @Kyson Yes, it looks correct. You just repeated the famous First Isomorphism Theorem's easy proof. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the map correctly, then you went on to show that it was additive, linear, surjective and injective (all correctly!), but you failed to show that it was well-defined in the first place!

Immediately after you defined the map, you need to show it's well-defined since we're dealing with cosets and their representatives. This amounts to supposing that $a + N = b + N$ and showing that $g(a + N) = g(b + N)$. If this isn't true, then we aren't dealing with a well-defined function (so everything you did afterwards would be meaningless).

Since $a + N = b + N$, then $a - b \in N$ by property of cosets which means that $f(a - b) = 0$ since $N = \ker f$ by hypothesis. Hence $f(a) = f(b)$ and thus we have $$g(a + N) = f(a) = f(b) = g(b + N)$$ as desired.